# How to integrate egnyte with Document and Media widget of liferay 7 or Is there any other way to integrate egnyte using third party application

Tags: liferay-7, facebook-workplace, egnyte

I am trying to integrate egnyte repository with liferay 7 using Document and Media widget to display the files and folders in UI.But since Document and Media supports CMIS web service and Atom url options. But didn't found option for integrating egnyte repository.Is that possible to integrate egnyte with liferay 7?